# Search for two strings within zip archives

Tags: linux, zip

Hope someone can help.

I have a series of zip files. These zip files contain email files (.eml)
I need to find all files between two people.

I can find on of them easily using an answer I found in here

```
for z in 2013-*.zip ; do zipgrep "PATTERN" $z | sed "s/^/$z: /" ; done
```

It's finding the second name within the identified files I am struggling with.

I have tried a second grep and zip grep on the file to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output? The names of matching zip files or the relevant lines?

Comment: names of the files ideally, along with the name of the originating zip file. If I pipe that to a text file I could use it to extract the relevant files .... unless there is a way of doing that as it finds a hit

Answer (score 1):

If the patterns are not necessarily on the same line, simple `zipgrep` can't do it, you will need to wrap it in a little script that checks if both patterns were found in the same file. Try something like:

```
for z in 2013-*.zip ; do 
   zipgrep "pat1" $z >/dev/null &&  
   zipgrep "pat2" $z >/dev/null && 
   echo $z; 
done
```

This will search each zip file for `pat1`, if it finds it (that's what the `&&` means)it will search for `pat2` and if it finds that as well it will print the name of the file. I am redirecting standard output (`>/dev/null`) so that only the file names are printed. If you want to see the relevant lines as well, do this instead:

```
for z in 2013-*.zip ; do 
   zipgrep "pat1" $z &&  
   zipgrep "pat2" $z && 
   echo $z; 
done
```

---

OK, this will print the zip file and the name of the matching file from within the zip file. It creates a temporary directory (`mktemp -d`), unzips each zip file into it and then deletes the directory. If you are working with large files that will take a while but I don't think there is any way of avoiding it.

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d tmp.XXXXX); for z in 2013-*.zip ; do 
    zipgrep "pat1" $z >/dev/null && zipgrep "pat2" $z > /dev/null && 
    unzip $z -d $tmpdir >/dev/null 2>&1;
    for i in $tmpdir/*; do 
        grep "pat1" $i  >/dev/null && 
        grep "pat2" $i  >/dev/null && 
        echo "$z : $i" | sed "s/$tmpdir.//"; 
    done;
done; rm -rf $tmpdir;
```

Comment: terdon - thanks for that. have put it into a little script and it works ... well sort of. It gives me the name of the originating zip file. Ideally I need the name of the file inside the zip as well in order for me to extract only the relevant files. ANy ideas on this one?

Comment: @Richard That's what the second choice does isn't it?

Comment: no, unfortunately it seems to throw out all the files that match each individual check. I have used an email conversation between myself and a colleague as a test and I get every email from myself and every email from the colleague, as well as the ones between the two of us

Comment: @Richard ah, yes I see why, it's because the zipfile actually contains both patterns but not necessarily in the same file. I assume each email is in its own `eml` file within the zipfile right?

Comment: @Richard see updated answer.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a go now. Unfortunately some of the files are going to contain a lot of eml files, but doing it this way I can actually copy out the matches before deleting the tmp folder

Comment: @Richard see updated answer, I modified it to only process those zip files that contain both matches, that should speed things up a little.